# Setting the Count Down Timer in Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, datepicker, countdowntimer

I'm using Date Picker, which is set to Count Down Timer mode. By default it displays the current time. How would I set it to display a specific time on start up? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a specific default time for a date picker in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33405710/how-to-set-a-specific-default-time-for-a-date-picker-in-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `date` property

[UIDatePicker > date](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker/1615975-date)

> Use this property to get and set the currently selected date